# Nextjs: Error: async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components

Tags: typescript, next.js13

I'm trying to create a navbar in nextjs 13. Although i didn't use "async/await" in navbar.tsx but it show that:" Nextjs: Error: async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components."
I don't know how to fix it.
This is my navbar.tsx:

```
"use client";
.....
export default function Navbar() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const firstName: string = AppUseSelector(
    (state) => state.AuthReducer.value.FIRST_NAME
  );....
  const handleSearch = () => {
    let key: string | undefined = (
      document.getElementById("searchInp") as HTMLInputElement
    )?.value.trim();
    router.push(`/product?key=${key}`);
  };
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    const options = {};
    const $targetEl = document.getElementById("subNavMobile");
    const $triggerEl = document.getElementById("triggerSubNavMobile");
    const collapse = new Collapse($targetEl, $triggerEl, options);
  }

  return (
    <header className=" sticky mb-4 shadow-sm  bg-[#3d71e7] ">
      ....
          {isAuth ? (
            <Link className="p-2 me-2" href={"/loginRegister"}>
              <Image
                src={avatar || "/img.png"}
                width={30}
                height={30}
                className="rounded-full"
                alt="avatar"
              />
              <span className="font-semibold hidden md:contents">
                {firstName}
              </span>
}
        ....

      {/* sidebar */}
               ....
            <DataManufactureNav />
             ....
      {/* main nav*/}
      <nav className="hidden md:block bg-white rounded p-2 w-fit mx-auto my-1 overflow-x-scroll w-full">
        <ul className="flex ">
          <DataManufactureNav />
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
}
```

And this is DataManufactureNav :

```
async function DataManufactureNav() {
  let dataManufactureNav: categoriesDTO[] | [] = [];
  if (typeof window == "undefined") {
    let res: Response;
    res = await fetch("http://localhost:8081/product/categories", {
      next: { revalidate: 3600 },
    });
    if (res.ok) {
      dataManufactureNav = await res.json();
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      {dataManufactureNav.length != 0 ? (
        dataManufactureNav?.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <li key={item.CATEGORY_ID}>
              <Link
                className="nav-link"
                href={`/categories/${item.CATEGORY_ID}`}
              >
                {item.CATEGORY_NAME}
              </Link>
            </li>
          );
        })
      ) : (
        <div>Something wrong</div>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: "didn't use async/await" yes, yes you did use it `async function DataManufactureNav()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are trying to import a server component `<DataManufactureNav />` inside your navbar client component. 
**Any child of a client component will be treated as a client component.**